# Naming repository method in springboot based on entity camelcase variable nam

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I know in spring boot that creating a find method in the repository will be base on the variable name of the entity. How can I create a find method in the repository if the variable in my entity is in a camel case. This is what I created is this right?

```
class Person { 
      private int id;  
      private Teacher teacher;  //other variable...getters and setters }
      private BranchManager branchManager;  //other variable...getters and setters }

class Teacher { 
      private String firstName ;  
      private String lastName;  //getters and setters }

class BranchManager { 
      private String firstName ;  
      private String lastName;  //getters and setters }
```

in my repository

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long>{


      public Person findPersonByTeacherFirstName(String firstName);

      //how to find Person by BranchManager firstName and lastName

}
```

Comment: have you tried with  `public Person findPersonByTeacher_firstName(String firstName);`

Comment: Use a Java 8. Stop writing crap like that.

Comment: @AluanHaddad do you have any suggestion or any example on how to do that Java 8. What would be the difference of using this and using Java 8. I'm just new to spring any suggestion suggestion would be greatly appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have not declared `Teacher` object in `Person`. Assuming that you will declare as follows

```
private Teacher teacher; // name of this object is important to create the repository methods
```

Try

```
List<Person> findByTeacher_FirstName(String name);
```

Note that it `findBy` returns a List.

If you want to return only the first record. You can use the following

```
Person findFirstByTeacher_FirstName(String name);
```

Also, Personally I prefer

```
Optional<Person> findFirstByTeacher_FirstName(String name);
```

as this will return Optional.empty() in case it couldn't find a record. Also, it will force you to check for its presence, thereby, avoiding NullPointerException.

**Update 1**

As requested in comment,
If you want to you want to find by firstName and lastName, you can use the following

```
Person findFirstByTeacher_FirstNameAndTeacher_LastName(String firstName, String lastName);
```

You can refer to this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) for these conventions.

**Update 2**

Search by branchManager's firstName and lastName

```
Person findFirstByBranchManager_FirstNameAndBranchManager_LastName(String firstName, String lastName);
```

**Update 3**

As mentioned by [Aluan Haddad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1915893/aluan-haddad) in comments, this practice is not scalable.

As an option, I am giving an alternative way to hit queries to DB.
You can create an example object and pass it to `findAll(Example e)` implementation of `JpaRepository`.

```
final Teacher exampleTeacher = new Teacher();
exampleTeacher.setName("Teacher Name");
final Person examplePerson = new Person();
example.setTeacher(exampleTeacher);
```

Now pass this `examplePerson` to `Repository` using

```
List<Person> findAll(Example.of(examplePerson));
```

This will return all the persons whose teacher's name is `Teacher Name`.

And as an alternative to C# EntityFramework, you can use [QueryDSL](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/tree/master/querydsl-jpa) in Java.

Comment: Thanks @ansh. Just want to ask another question. The same with the above scenario. I want to find a person by teacher. In the above example the parameter needed is just firstName what if now I want to search the person also by teacher but I want to search it with firstName and lastName. How can I do that. TIA

Comment: Last question @ansh. I have another object inside the Person object. The name of that object is BranchManager (note that name is in camel case). Like the Teacher object it also has firstName and lastName property. I also want to search the Person by its Branch Manager firstName and lastName. I updated  my question and add the Branch Manager Class.

Comment: You can create a similar method, the only thing to keep in mind is `branchManager` will become `findByBranchManager...`

Comment: Such an awful coding practice to accumulate this sickening amount of unmaintainable cruft in the form of ad hoc query methods taking miscellaneous strings. You have basic lambda expression in Java now (primitive but still better than this) make use of them!

Comment: Woahh !! Did u mean, to get a record from a table of large datasets using lambda expressions?

You mean to get list of Persons whose Teacher_Id = 1, I must fetch all the Persons (with join over the respective teachers) and then do filtering through PRIMITIVE lambdas

Comment: Can use lambdas to pass in a query criteria object, although come to think of it, you don't even need a lambda for that. Just pass in a query criteria object.

Comment: I have never said that this is the best coding practice, neither I am against it. Many of the times its better to hit the DB rather than performing in-memory operations.

Also, this answer does its job to resolve someone's query. If you are interested in making it more elegant and scalable then you must see `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`.

Comment: Just this sort of code is disturbing. Let your ORM handle it. Hibernate and HQL or whatever you use.

Comment: Its about premature optimization and maintainability. Java is supposed to be about writing maintainable code, but there is so _much_ code it is frankly a joke. Lobby for Expression Trees, or switch to Scala.

Comment: But sometimes it better not to over-engineer at a very early stage, where you are actually spending lot of time in writing criteria builder for individual entities.

Comment: They are cheap to maintain if you use a common interface that declares your fields. Honestly, that entire repository, no models or criteria required, is about 10 lines of C# including imports

Comment: Common interface for all the entities?